# How to filter with URL parameters in Laravel 4?

Tags: url, laravel, filter, laravel-4

Let's say I'm paginating a list of items, and want to filter them by the first letter, my URL would be something like `myURL.com/items?sortBy=C&page=2`, this would return me the page 2 of the items that start with C. (Pagination is already working)

My question is, how do I retrieve the `sortBy=C`? And how the `routes.php`, and the controller would look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use the `Input::get()`, it takes the query string into consideration.

So, in your controller:

```
$letter = Input::get('sortBy');
```

You don't have to worry about your routes or your controller (I mean, you don't have to pass extra variables or check segments).

Example:

```
Route::get('items', array('as' => 'items', 'uses' => 'ItemsControllers@items'));

function items()
{
  $sort = Input::get('sortBy');

  // OR, if you want, you can check first for the index:
  if (Input::has('sortBy')) {
   $sort = Input::get('sortBy');
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, wow, didn't know Input::get() worked like that, thought it'd only work with the inputs inside forms, Thanks!